# What does "way" mean in "no way"?

Tags: meaning

Google dictionary shows [18 meanings for *way*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&q=way&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&psj=1&ei=11AHUOfQDsHrrQe2-fDWAg&ved=0CEsQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ccd452f04fdfaa98&biw=819&bih=538). Among which, we have:

1. A method, style, or manner of doing something
2. A person's characteristic or habitual manner of behavior or expression
3. The typical manner in which something happens or in which someone or something behaves
4. A specified direction
5. Used with a verb and adverbial phrase to intensify the force of an action or to denote movement or progress
6. A particular aspect of something; a respect
7. A specified condition or state

Which of these is the meaning for the "way" in "no way", the informal term which means absolutely no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of those, since it's short for ***in*** no way.

The phrase is simply an emphatic [Negative](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf).

- *No way am I going there.* (Note the [subject-verb inversion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/anyquestions.pdf) with adverb fronting)

If you won't go there in any way, you won't go there at all.

- A: *He'll be mad at you.*
- B: *No way.*

***A*** thinks that he'll be mad at ***B***, but ***B*** denies that; if there is no way in which he'll be mad at ***B***, then he won't be mad at ***B*** at all.

Etc.

Comment: In the sentence *"if there is no way in which he'll be mad at B..."*, what does the "way" mean? How can we rewrite the sentence without using the word "way"?

Comment: _In no manner, in no situation, under no conditions,_ ...

Comment: what do you think of Russel's answer?

Comment: As I said, any of those senses would work, including the ***Journey*** [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is somewhat idiomatic, so doesn't carry exactly any of the meanings above.  Meaning 1 is closest, but closest would be "way" in the sense of a route towards a goal.  "No way" is simply a contraction of "there is no way that could be possible" i.e. the speaker is (hyperbolically) suggesting that they simply don't believe the previous speaker's statement is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the definitions you didn't offer:

*A course of travel or route taken in order to reach a place*

In the phrase *no way* it's used in varying degrees of metaphoricity, from the fairly literal sense of "a path":

```
"We need to get to the other side of the river."
"[There's] no way [to get there from here]."
```

...to a more figurative "sequence of events":

```
"I need you to go out there and draw their fire while I sneak around behind them."
"[There's] no way [you can convince me to do that]."
"Not even for a Scooby Snack?"
"Well... okay."
```